# Jquery getting new value after data attribute update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updating link attribute values via ajax response.but When i am again clicking the button/link getting old values instead of new value.

Below is my codes;

### HTML

```
<div class="calendar-control"><a class="evecal-month-view-control fright next-month" href="#" data-month="2" data-year="2019">Next</a><span class="text-center month-name">January 2019</span><a class="evecal-month-view-control fright prev-month" href="#" data-month="12" data-year="2018">Previous</a></div>
```

And Jquery code.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.evecal-month-view-control', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var month = jQuery(this).data('month');
    var year = jQuery(this).data('year');
    console.log(month);
    _getMonthCalendar(month, year);
});

var _getMonthCalendar = function(m, y){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: eventcaldata.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'ec_ajax_month_table',
            year: y,
            month: m,
            nonce: eventcaldata.nonce,
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log('sending...');
        },
        success: function(response){
            jQuery('.next-month').attr( 'data-month', response.nextmonth.month );
            jQuery('.next-month').attr( 'data-year', response.nextmonth.year );
            jQuery('.prev-month').attr( 'data-month', response.prevmonth.month);
            jQuery('.prev-month').attr( 'data-year', response.prevmonth.year);
        }
    });
}
```

> First on `.next-month` class the `data-month` attribute value is `2`
>   then it is changed to `3` after response.But When i am again clicking
>   that button i am getting `2` value when it should be `3`

Answer (score 4):

The .data() method on jQuery objects caches the value from the initial read. Subsequent call to .data() will first look in jQuery's data storage and send you that value. .attr() won't update the data storage, but will update the attribute in HTML. Use either .data() or .attr() but avoid mix and match.

Answer (score 1):

Do not intermix this usage of `attr()` and `data()`.  `data()` caches the value that it reads from the element, and does not update the attribute.  So if you update with data, attr will not see it.  Pick one or the other, and stick with it.